# Prove that $f(x) = x$ is the unique solution to the following functional equation

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f : [0 , \infty) \to \mathbb{R},$  continuous at $  x_0 = 0$ satisfying
$$f(3x) - 2x = f(x)$$
Prove that $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Okay, the question doesn't show effort, but that's too much downvoting.

Comment: All such functions are $f(x)=x+c$.

Comment: Yes,i managed to show that function we searched for had a linear form.

Comment: Well, if you could prove it had a linear form you'd be done.  As a hint to get started:  suppose you had two such functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  What can you say about $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$?

Comment: I can scroll down the most recent list and find questions that display no effort, but are upvoted. What influences people's decisions around here?

Comment: @Kaynex There are many accepts, downvotes, upvotes , closevotes, whatsoever on this site, I will never understand.

Comment: Beats me.. If i had a good idea on how the problem was solved i would've written it :/

Comment: Personally I think this is a good question. You have my upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(3x)=2x+f(x)
         =2x+2x/3+f(x/3)
          =2x+2x/3+2x/9+f(x/9)$
$2+2/3+2/9+...=2*1/(1-1/3)=3$.   By continued on 0  $f(3x)=3x$

Comment: while editing, please translate into English